# android - bit confused on when to use threads & when to use services?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am writing an android application to make server socket and receive messages from server

when I write the same application using Thread, it works pretty well but I am unable to access UI elements in Thread

whereas in case of services, startService method hangs on while(true){ socket.accept()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about threads and Android on the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). Also, take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), that should help you a great lot.

Comment: I want to write code in diffrent classes and access ui elemeents from there .... I tiried asynctask also its very similar to timer ..... but can you tell me on how to access UI from a diffrent thread?